# HTML form return displays python code instead of executing

Tags: python, html, forms

Coming from only basic front end experience here and running into trouble using method="get" on my python script.

The entire python code is returned to the browser instead of just the print statement.  I am using python SimpleHTTPServer and expect that I may be missing some configuration, but I am having quite a bit of trouble determining a solution.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form name="search" action="\cgi-bin/test.py" method="get">
  Search: <input type="text" name="searchbox">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the Python (and also what gets returned to the browser when the form is submitted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm =  form.getvalue('searchbox')
print(searchterm)
```

I know this is probably pretty basic, but I am stumped.  I appreciate any guidance to be offered.

Comment: if this is Linux then you have to set it executable - `chmod +x test.py` - and then you can run this script in console using only `test.py` instead of `python test.py`

Comment: as I rememer `SimpleHTTPServer` doesn't run `CGI` if you don't set it. At least when you run it in console you have to use `--cgi` in command `python3 -m http.server --cgi`

Comment: do you use Python 2 or Python 3 ? As I remeber `SimpleHTTPServer` exists only in Python 2, and you may have to use [CGIHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html) instead of `SimpleHTTPServer` - ie. `python2 -m CGIHTTPServer`

Comment: BTW: you forgot `print("Content-Type: text/html")` and empty line `print()` to send it as HTML. If you don't use it then it may treat it as file which you want to download.

Comment: maybe better learn [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) - it can be more useful. `CGI` is old and probably nobody use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Python 2` then you should use `CGIHTTPServer` instead of `SimpleHTTPServer`

```
python2 -m CGIHTTPServer
```

If you use `Python 3` then you should use `http.server --cgi`

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

---

And code has to be executable.

On Linux you do:

```
chmod +x cgi-bin/test.py
```

On Windows you have to assign extension `.py` to `python`. I don't use Windows to give more info.

---

Script has to send information what type of data it sends - text, HTML, image, PDF, Excel, etc. - and empty line which separates header and body.

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()    # empty line beetwin header and body
print(searchterm)
```

Without this information it may send it as file for downloading.

---

If you want to display text in console then you may have to use "standard error" because `"standard output"` and `print()` is send to browser

```
import sys

sys.stderr.write(searchterm + '\n')
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi
import sys

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm = form.getvalue('searchbox')

# send text on console
sys.stderr.write('searchterm: ' + searchterm + '\n')

# send text to browser
#print("Content-Type: text/plain") # send all as text
print("Content-Type: text/html")   # send all as HTML
print() 
print(searchterm)
```